# hi i want to generate a code to programmatically obtain tweets, retweets and likes from a given twitter account between two timestamps, is this right?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

```
import datetime
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

start_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 23, 0, 0, 0)

def get_tweets_retweets_likes(username):
    # Get the tweets for the user
    tweets = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(
f"from:{username} since:{start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} until:{end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
).get_items()

    # Count the number of tweets, retweets, and likes
    number_of_tweets = 0
    number_of_retweets = 0
    number_of_likes = 0
    
    for tweet in tweets:
        number_of_tweets += 1
        number_of_likes += tweet.likeCount
        if tweet.retweetCount > 0:
            number_of_retweets += 1
    
    # Return the results
    return number_of_tweets, number_of_retweets, number_of_likes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace the link with your own
    link = "https://twitter.com/elonmusk?s=20"

    # Extract the username from the link
    username = link.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
    
    number_of_tweets, number_of_retweets, number_of_likes = get_tweets_retweets_likes(username)
    
    # Print the results
    print(start_time)
    print(end_time)
    print(f"Number of tweets: {number_of_tweets}")
    print(f"Number of retweets: {number_of_retweets}")
    print(f"Number of likes: {number_of_likes}")
```

if above answer is incorrect, i want the correct one. Please help!`

Comment: How can we know if the answer is incorrect?  Does it work?  Does it do what you want?

Comment: What result are you getting? What result did you expect? Any error messages? What exactly is the problem you need help with? You can't expect people on SO to run your code, guess what you wanted exactly, and then rewrite your code accordingly if something seems wrong. Have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: oh i'm sorry for the confusion,      output is 2023-06-20 00:00:00
2023-06-26 00:00:00
Number of tweets: 169
Number of retweets: 169
Number of likes: 5780324

Comment: as you see the number of retweets is incorrect, can someone please give me the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

If there are any retweets for a particular tweet you just add 1 to number_of_retweets. You should add the retweetCount. Here's the code fixed and tidied up...

```
from snscrape.modules.twitter import TwitterSearchScraper as TSS, Tweet
import os
import sys

def get_tweets(username: str, start: str, end: str) -> list[Tweet]:
    query = f"from:{username} since:{start} until:{end}"
    _stderr = sys.stderr
    try:
        with open(os.devnull, 'a') as nul:
            sys.stderr = nul
            return [item for item in TSS(query).get_items() if isinstance(item, Tweet)]
    finally:
        sys.stderr = _stderr


if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = 'elonmusk'
    start = '2023-06-18'
    end = '2023-06-23'

    nTweets = len(tweets := get_tweets(username, start, end))
    nLikes = nRetweets = 0

    for tweet in tweets:
        nLikes += tweet.likeCount
        nRetweets += tweet.retweetCount

    print(start)
    print(end)
    print(f"Number of tweets: {nTweets:,}")
    print(f"Number of retweets: {nRetweets:,}")
    print(f"Number of likes: {nLikes:,}")
```

**Output:**

```
2023-06-18
2023-06-23
Number of tweets: 156
Number of retweets: 491,084
Number of likes: 5,876,053
```